# How to draw Image under existing text in pdf using core graphics

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, core-graphics

I want to draw watermark image beneath existing PDF text content. Currently i can able to draw image above existing content using core graphics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution for my own problem. I have solved the problem by changing the order of drawing in the target context.

Comment: Hi, Sorry i can't give you the code, as it didn't contains anything special, the trick is as i mentioned above is changed the order of drawing. For Example: if you need to draw watermark below existing pdf content, then create new nsimage with the size of pdf page media/art box size, and then first draw the watermark and then draw the pdf page in the graphic context. Hope this will help. :)

Comment: can you provide the watermark code ?

Comment: As i said in my above comment, there is nothing special, just try to do as i suggested. I'll try to send you some code if possible.